# Can the way a site is coded affect how much we spend on hosting?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hosting, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Our website is an eCommerce store trading in ethically sourced loose diamonds. We do not get much traffic and yet our Amazon bill is huge ($300/month for 1,500 unique visits). Is this normal?

I do know we are daily doing some database pulling twice from another source and that the files are large. Does it make sense to just use regular hosting for this process and then the Amazon one just for our site?

Most of the cost is for Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud. About 20% is for RDS service.

I am wondering if:

(a) our developers have done something which leads to this kind of usage OR
(b) Amazon is just really expensive

**IS THERE A PAID FOR SERVICE WHICH WE CAN USE TO ENSURE OUR SITE IS OPTIMISED FOR ITS HOSTING** - in terms of cost, usage and speed?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about pricing.

Comment: yes it may appear about pricing, but really I am wondering if technically it is possible for a site to be using more than it should be due to the way it has been coded and/or set-up to the hosting provider?

Comment: I have made some changes. Is the question suitable now?

Comment: $300.00 for 1,500 unique visitors is ridiculous. What sized instance are you running?

Comment: I am sorry, I have no idea. This is why I am here. Looking for a way to check the quality of the job that has been done. Am willing to pay a little for a brief audit on the setup of the hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should probably cost you around 30-50 dollars a month. 300 seems higher than necessary.

for 1500 vistors, you can get away with using an m1.small instance most likely

I'd say check out the AWS trusted advisor service that will tell you about your utilization and where you can optimize your usage, but you can only get that with AWS Business support (100/month). However considering your way over what is expected, it might be worth looking into

Trusted advisor will inform you of quite a few things:

- cost optimization
- security
- fault tolerance
- performance

I've generally found it to be one of the most useful additions to my AWS infrastructure.

Additionally if you were to sign up for Business support, not only do you get trusted advisor, but you can ask questions directly to the support staff via chat, email, or phone. Would also be quite useful to help you pinpoint your problem areas.